# jquery Check the year of a datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

i'm using the datepicker from jqueryui in a form. Now i want to validate the year of birth. This means that my user can't put in a year that is higher than 1998 (he/she must be 18 years old). How can i check if the value isn't higher than 1998? This is what i've so far.

`<input type="text" id="birthyear" required><br />`

```
$(function(){
    $('#birthyear').datepicker({
        minDate: new Date(1900,1-1,1),
        defaultDate: new Date(1991,1-1,1),
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '-110:-18'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object from the datepicker using getDate:

```
var date = $("#birthyear").datepicker("getDate");
```

From there you can get the year:

```
var year = date.getFullYear();
```

If you want to make sure the user is at least 18 years old, you might want to check more than just the year: you'll also want to make sure today's date is after their 18th birthday.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways I can see to achieve this

1. Set a max cut-off date to prevent anyone from even selecting a date past your determined

   ```
   $('#birthyear').datepicker({
       minDate: new Date(1900,1-1,1),
       defaultDate: new Date(1991,1-1,1),
       changeYear: true,
       yearRange: '-110:-18',
       maxDate: new Date(1997, 11, 31)
   });
   ```
2. Bind a validation function to the `onChangeMonthYear` event on initialisation

   ```
   $('#birthyear').datepicker({
       minDate: new Date(1900,1-1,1),
       defaultDate: new Date(1991,1-1,1),
       changeYear: true,
       yearRange: '-110:-18',
       onChangeMonthYear: function(year) {
           if (year > 1998)
               ; // alert user of error
       }
   });
   ```
3. A little trickier, but if you've got some client-side validation function already, you can get the `Date` object like this:

   ```
   $('#birthyear').datepicker('getDate').getFullYear()
   ```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I see some of the other answers are showing you how to confirm the year but years pass by. I had a similar requirement for a project that required the users age to be verified and rather than hard coding a year, and though you are requesting to check the year(but with the age requirements in parentheses) I would suggest a more dynamic and maintainable solution as provided below.

```
    //Initialize datepicker
         $(function() {
                $( "#dob" ).datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,//allow month select
                    changeYear: true,//allow year select
                    yearRange: "-100:+0",//set range of year select
                    dateFormat: 'MM dd, yy',//set format of "displayed element"
                    altField: "#hidden-dob",//set alt field "hidden element"
                    altFormat: "yy/mm/dd",//set format for hidden element
                    onClose: function() {
                        $('#hidden-age').val(getUserAge($('#hidden-dob').val()));
                    }
                });
            });
    //year/month/day

//Pass the date to retrieve the users age FORMAT <yy/mm/dd> "The function that you need"
            function getUserAge(dateString) {
                var today = new Date();
                var dob = new Date(dateString);
                var age = today.getFullYear() - dob.getFullYear();
                var month = today.getMonth() - dob.getMonth();
                if (month < 0 || (month === 0 && today.getDate() < dob.getDate())) {
                    age--;
                }
                return age;
            }
```